# SQL - Only need the record with Max Date

Tags: sql

My table looks something like this:

[image]

I want to get the record for the MAX Date. So after querying, my output should only contain this:

[image]

Comment: Your database tags are inconsistent, so I removed them.  Tag only with the dtabase you are reallyusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated subquery is a simple method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.update_date = (select max(t2.update_date) from t t2 where t2.number = t.num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` with `top (1) with ties` available for SQL Server (which was initially tagged) :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by no order by date desc);
```

You can also use subquery :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by no order by date desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```